# Backing up Entities and related BlobStores in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backup, blobstore

I have an AppEngine Java application and there are various entities that I want to backup. The catch is that some of the entities have BlobKeys saved in an attribute, and the data is put in the BlobStore.

My requirement is to backup the entire database i.e. entities and Blobstore data. The experimental Datastore Admin utility, I understand backs up only the entity data and not the BlobStore.

What do you suggest is the best way forward given that my current data storage is split across entities and blobstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the blobs into Google Cloud Storage rather than the blobstore. Then you can use the tools provided (e.g. gsutil) to take a backup of the blobs.

There is no way to do this with blobs stored in blobstore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That might not be the solution currently since it will mean changing stuff from Blobstore to GCS. Lets assume for the moment that I eventually do migrate to GCS, my main worry is as follows: 1) I have an entity called Attachments in which one of the fields is actually the Blobstore key. So I first put my attachment in the Blobstore and then use that key to insert in the Attachments Entity. So if I individually export Attachments entity and GCS stuff, will this ID be retained, when imported back or I need some specific routines?

Comment: if the file is in GCS then why wouldn't you just record the GCS name as part of your entity?

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately I did not do it that way and used the ID instead, which I believe will now create problems for me when trying to actually do a cohesive export and then an import. Still many thanks for your answer.